# Pass variable through shell script via crontab?

Tags: sh, cron, ping

Is there a way to pass a variable through a cron job? Example, currently I have a cron job setup like so:

`* * * * * /bin/bash /Volumes/raid/farm_script/_apps/_scripts/farm_ping.sh`

I'm wondering, is it possible to pass through info to the shell script from the cron job? Something similar to this perhaps:

`* * * * * /bin/bash /Volumes/raid/farm_script/_apps/_scripts/farm_ping.sh 192.168.2.17`

If so, how could I access this inside the `farm_ping.sh` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a positional parameter, accessible as `$1`. The next one would be `$2`.